Can't dupe-hammer a Staging Ground question after it was voted off-topic and submitted for re-evaluation
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78628790
Initially, the question was voted as off-topic as caused by a typo or not reproducible. In my view this is incorrect; rather the question simply lacked debugging details and/or focus (specifically, a complete error message). The example could be a bit more minimal, but even I'd agree that's a fairly minor quibble. And the formatting is not great, but that could be fixed easily enough by a third party.
OP edited to show the error and generally clarify the question. Given the error message, I was able to find what I'm pretty sure is a duplicate, but now the "Vote as duplicate" option is greyed out. I could presumably fix this by approving and then dupe-hammering on the main site, but I think the SG interface should let me vote it as a duplicate directly.

This is intended AFAIK. It is not possible to move from one closed state to another (without a "Major/Minor Changes" in between) and once you voted to close a post, you cannot do so again.

It wasn't my vote, though. Also I feel like "closed state" is an awkward distinction for a SG question since they already can't receive answers. In my mind, the relevance of the "typo" and "duplicate" statuses is "the question likely cannot be fixed". But especially for typos, OP should have a chance to fix it anyway (maybe the typo occurred during posting, not in the actual code!) and maybe that will surface a different issue.

It's also weird to call it a "closed state" when any SG reviewer can unilaterally overturn it and approve the question as if it had just been posted. More generally, I feel like more thought should go in to what happens when SG reviewers disagree.

I call it "closed state" because I have no better name for the union of closed and duplicate. Both of them are practically the same (the difference to "Requires Major Changes" is that it's harder to get to and the UI is a bit different) If it's in a closed state, it cannot change to another closed state. In that case, you can write a comment about it and use the "Requires Major Changes" option. During the beta, there was a feature request about changing the duplicate target but that was declined as it's an edge case.

It's not that bad if a post is close and there's a comment pointing out a duplicate. Getting from one closed state to another is possible by switching to "Requires Major Changes" and then two different reviewers (who haven't voted to close before) closing it again. I don't know whether someone closing it as a duplicate can then (later) vote to close it as something else (after "Major Changes") but I don't think so.

Anyways in the Staging Ground, voting to close something as off-topic (not talking about duplicates) is something that should be avoided in the majority of cases (posts should be improved rather than stopped) and there was also discussion to completely remove it during the beta.

Closed by a typo or closed by being a duplicate does it really matter the reason it was closed?

@SecurityHound again this is a lot to do with the semantics of "closed" vis-a-vis how SG works.
